# How to achieve a 'Wait' mode in Powershell Get-Process

Tags: powershell

**Get-Process** cmdlet returns every process that is running **and then control returns to powershell**.
For example, running this in powershell, i get:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Get-Process -Name thunderbird

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   1791     139   193596     186964     551.86  13552   1 thunderbird
    723      45   194640     198084       4.81  16772   1 thunderbird
   1012      68    45068      41648       0.78  18328   1 thunderbird

 PS C:\Users\me>
```

Is there a way to keep it **running** and update when another thunderbird process starts?

Comment: Surely all you need is a while loop?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Get-Counter`

Answer (score 3):

add it to the infinite loop

as following:

```
do{
get-process
start-sleep 5} 
while(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this solution you will end up with your whole screen filled from the same process each time sleeps end. It is not a wait&update on change mode, but mostly a constant printing on intervals

Comment: Turns out this was the right answer, just needed a cls at the start of the loop if you didn't want a scrolling screen

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Overcomplicated it for a sec there! The below also updates when instances are closed.

```
do{
cls
Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}while(1)
```

Old code

```
$proc = Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$proc
do{
$update = Get-Process -Name notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($update -ne $proc){
    $update | Where-Object -Property Id -NotIn $proc.Id
    $proc = $update
}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}while(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this kind of solution can work, but filter out by Process Id and not by Process Name. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if it possible to stack the output host? Cls will clear permanently the console. It would be nice if we could do a scoped cls and revert to original status when exiting from this loop

Comment: Did you edit your answer to include the code from someone else's answer?

Comment: No haha, I wrote the first solution then realised I'd had a brain fart and did the 2nd...then realised it was almost exactly what mohamed had already written hence upvoting his answer instead.